# How to use a button or a hyperlink to activate a piece of code?

Tags: php, html

I'd like to know how I could activate a piece of code (perhaps start a timer) using a button or hyperlink. I tried using a function or onclick in a href but I couldn't get that working.

```
<a href="?start=true" onclick=myFunction()>Start</a>
```

I tried the above, and I searched around, but no one seemed to have my specific answer.
I probably did a lot of mess ups in the code, but I'm taking a shot in the dark. Hey, at least I tried something :\
Sorry if I seem like a complete idiot. I do that a lot.

> ?start=true

Just doesn't seem too correct to me, but I barely use that sort of user-query thing, so I'm very unfamiliar. Any help is appreciated!
For clarification: I want it to start a timer and the person has a certain amount of time to click an answer. Like a minigame, only PHP & HTML.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean.  If you want some code to run in the browser (on the user's machine) then you want javascript.  You marked this as a php question.

Comment: `onclick` has nothing to do with PHP... nothing at all.  In fact, nothing in your question has anything to do with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotes...

```
<a href="?start=true" onclick="myFunction()">Start</a>
```